# Python telegram randomizer with pictures

Tags: python, random, bots, telegram

How can i fix this error?

```
PS C:\Users\Rodya> python tryprc.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rodya\tryprc.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Rodya\tryprc.py", line 38, in main
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Updater.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'
```

In this code:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext
import time
import random

TOKEN = "TOKEN"
OPTIONS = {
    "Cпокойная гонка": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\1.png",
    "Легкая прямая": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\2.png",
    "По острию вершины": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\3.png",
    "Руины у озера": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\4.png",
    "Озеро Скрэйпер": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\5.png",
    "Прохват по высоте": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\6.png",
    "Гонка на стройке": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\7.png",
    "Пустынная деревня": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\8.png",
    "Храмовые промежутки": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\9.png",
    "Тур по местности": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\10.png",
    "Dive сквозь замок": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\11.png",
    "Терминал прибытия": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\12.png",
    "Трамплин": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\13.png",
    "Парк новичков": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\14.png",
    "Долгая дорога": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\15.png",
    "Тур по пирамиде": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\16.png",
    "Прохват по храму": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\17.png",
    "Узкий коридор": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\18.png",
    "Знаток каменоломни": "C:\\Users\\Rodya\\Desktop\\Tryprc\\19.png",
}

def start(update, context: CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="*Следующая трасса для гонок:*", parse_mode="Markdown")

    time.sleep(15)  

    option, image_path = random.choice(list(OPTIONS.items()))
    message = f"{option}\n[Картинка]({image_path})"
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=message, parse_mode="Markdown")

def main():
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if name == 'main':
    main()
```

There should be some random names and pics.
I tried to downgrade version of python and telegram bot library, but it doesnt make any sence.
What im supposed to do?

I tried google and use chat gpt, but there is no answer on this question. Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe read latest documentation for version `20.x` - [Your-first-Bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions---Your-first-Bot). It doesn't use `Update()` but `ApplicationBuilder().token()`. ChatGPT may have information for much older version `13.x`. See [Your-first-Bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot) for `13.x` - it uses `Updater()`